How to process the byte array so that the pixels in QLabel are displayed as when using matplotlib cmap="gray"?
Software is being developed to edit a dataset with a specific extension and structure. It is required to put the resulting image into a QLabel, but when reading the data in Format_Grayscale16 mode, it is darker than when opening matplotlib with the "grey" color map.
QLabel code:
ds=dcmread(*filepath*)
imQt=QImage(ds.pixel_array,ds.Columns,ds.Rows,ds.Columns*2, QImage.Format.Format_Grayscale16)
pix=QPixmap.fromImage(imQt)
Img_View_label.setPixmap(self.pix.scaled(self.Img_View_label.width(),
Img_View_label.height(),QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio))



matplotlib code:
ds=dcmread(path)
    
im=Image.fromarray(ds.pixel_array)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(im,cmap="grey")

plt.show()


How should the data be processed?

Are you sure that original pixel array is in Format_Grayscale16? Have you tried to check it in any graphic viewer/editor? I would assume that you may use wrong format of pixels... As another step I would look into alpha-channel - i.e. you may get pixelColor() and then use alpha() or setAlpha() methods. And what is Img_View_label? May it be in Disabled state by any chance?... (that would also fade image out under some conditions...)

@StarterKit  Yes, i'm sure that it's Grayscale16 because of format of data after ds.pixel_array is ndarray_uint16. Img_View_Label is a QLabel where i display data. My pixels in dicom fule has only 1 channel. Also i'd like to say that i solve problem by open image in pyplot and copy to buffer with resize. After that i got the same image in Img_View_Label
